# Alpha/Beta Parameters of BJT

Tags: transistors, bjt

The BJT Current equations are given as :-

I<sub>E</sub> = I<sub>C</sub> + I<sub>B</sub>

I<sub>C</sub> = \$\alpha\$ I<sub>E</sub>

I<sub>C</sub> = \$\beta\$ I<sub>B</sub>

Does the relations with \$\alpha\$ and  \$\beta\$ parameters include the reverse saturation  current I<sub>CBO</sub>  also ? Or should it be added separately ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first equation you wrote is correct.

$$I_E = I_C+I_B \tag1 $$

But he other two equations are written by neglecting the reverse saturation currents \$I_{CBO}\$ and \$I_{CEO}\$. The original equations are:

$$\begin{align} I_C &= \alpha I_E + I_{CBO} \tag{2}\\
I_C &= \beta I_B + I_{CEO}\\
&=\beta I_B + (\beta +1)I_{CBO} \tag{3}\end{align}$$